# How do you find Fourier series coefficients for some weird waveform?

Tags: fourier

The formulae for the Fourier series coefficients contain f(x), e.g.

$$ b_n = \frac 1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)sin(nx)dx $$

But if I don't know what f(x) is, e.g.

[image: wave1]

or

[image: wave3]

then how can I get the coefficients?

Comment: You could use a numerical approach. Capture the data to digital form, then compute the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: You can still use algebra - just approximate each section to a part of a sinewave or straight line or whatever and integrate in sections

Comment: If you **do not know** what \$f(x)\$ is then you can't compute the fourier coefficients.

Comment: f(x) represents the waveshape of your "weird waveform".  If it makes you feel better, you can replace the variable "x" with a "t" for time but he result is the same.

Comment: Andy, if you write that as an 'answer', I'll 'accept' it.

Answer (score 1):

If the periodic time can be determined by inspection, you can proceed numerically and use Fourier Series analysis. In this case, Fourier Series is probably better than Fourier Transform, since: the FT is not particularly accurate in the calculation of phase angles; FS is potentially faster than FT (or FFT); it's preferable to use all available a-priori knowledge of a signal, rather than discard it; the FS can be derived quite simply using, e.g., Excel, whereas calculating the FT is not as straightforward, so you'd probably need access to a package.

If the waveform is not periodic, or if the periodic time is not easily discernible (eg the fundamental frequency may not be present in the signal), then the FT is indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a symbolic expression, apply the formula for the transform.

If you have an unknown waveform, you can use an FFT algorithm. Just capture it with a digital scope, then throw it into [Excel](http://www.stem2.org/je/Excel_FFT_Instructions.pdf)